# For what definition of the continuity is the continuity at infinity possible?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

For what definition of the continuity is the continuity at infinity possible?

For example, let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)=x$. By intuition, since $f$ is always continuous, at infinity it's also continuous.

Formally, we must have $lim_{x \to \infty+}\ f(x)=lim_{x \to \infty-}\ f(x)$ but this is nonsense because you can't approach plus infinity from the left and from the right. It is not a number.

OR

$lim_{a \to \infty}lim_{x \to a+}\ f(x)=lim_{a \to \infty}lim_{x \to a-}\ f(x)$

in which case two-sided limit at infinity is the same as one-sided and therefore it is defined?

Comment: Because infinity isn't a number in $\ \mathbb{R}\ $, it doesn't make much sense to talk about "continuity $at$ infinity", because $x$ never equals infinity. Your question might make more sense if you re-formulate it in terms of the *extended* real number system. - although even then I'm not sure. And even if it did make sense in that setting, I doubt it will be particularly fruitful.

Comment: As Adam mentioned, one way to give meaning to 'continuity at infinity' is to consider the real projective line $\mathbb P^1(\mathbb R) = \mathbb R \cup \{ \infty \}$. Intuitively you can think of this as wrapping the real line around a circle, and having the remaining point be your infinity. 'continuity at infinity' is then given by having the same limit when approaching it from either side, that is the limit towards $+\infty$ and $-\infty$, which fits your intuition. A function is then 'continuous at infinity' if and only if it can be extended to $\mathbb P^1(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: In general, we only talk about the limit *per se*. The fact that you can *additionally* talk about limit from the left and from the right is an artefact coming from the fact that a real number has its neighbourhoods extend in two (and only two!) directions.

Comment: Someday perhaps you will study point-set topology, and you will learn lots of ways to talk about the notion "continuous".

Answer (score 1):

For a real function $f$ defined on a norm vector space $X$, the following definition of limit at $\infty$ makes sense (and is used in several math domains):

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)=l$$ if and only if for all $\epsilon \gt 0$ it exists $M \ge 0$ such that for all $\Vert x \Vert \gt M$ we have $\vert f(x) -l\vert \lt \epsilon$.

Based on this definition, the limit at $\infty$ of $f(x)=1/x$ is equal to zero. In a similar way the map $g(x)=1/\Vert x \Vert $ defined on a Banach space $(X, \Vert \cdot \Vert)$ has for limit $0$ at $\infty$.

See [point at infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_at_infinity?wprov=sfti1).